# How to revoke all priviledges and roles from the user?

Tags: roles, hana, privileges, sql-revoke, database-roles

Anyone have written a stored procedure which can remove all assigned roles/privileges from given user ? I like to do this without looking up each role assigned or privilege assigned. 
Similar like below statement but without listing each role and privileges one by one. Removal all roles/privilege in one single statement regardless of what role assigned. This is for user termination process.

CALL REVOKE_ACTIVATED_ROLE('RoleName','username');

Answer (score 2):

Well if you really want the procedure, I'm using this one and it works.

It removes all the granted roles from the user. Run it if you know what you are doing.

```
create procedure myCleanupUser(in i_user varchar(20)) as
begin
    declare cursor Roles for
        SELECT ROLE_NAME FROM "PUBLIC"."EFFECTIVE_ROLES" 
        where USER_NAME=i_user AND GRANTEE_TYPE='USER' AND ROLE_NAME <> 'PUBLIC';

    for role as Roles do
        call REVOKE_ACTIVATED_ROLE(role.ROLE_NAME,i_user);
    end for;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no such standard functionality available and I recommend to be **very** careful with automatically revoking privileges. If the user himself granted privileges that he got granted with ADMIN OPTION or with GRANT OPTION to other users and these privileges get revoked, this leads to a recursive revocation of those granted privileges.

In short: this can become nasty.

For user termination, it's sufficient from a security point of view to disable the logon.

Other than that, it's pretty straight forward to query system view GRANTED_ROLES and GRANTED_PRIVILEGES to generate the REVOKE statements.

Comment: > "If the user himself granted privileges that he got granted with ADMIN
> OPTION or with GRANT OPTION to other users and these privileges get
> revoked, this leads to a recursive revocation of those granted
> privileges."

Above statement is not true. I do not think there is recursive revocation if user looses the privileges. I could remove all roles assigned to X user who granted Y privileges to other user and it does not get revoked.

My original question is when I terminate, I remove all roles from given user as a part of our standard process. I am trying automates process same process.

Comment: The above statement actually is true and even documented: https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/fc91cb75191014ac15eb4d6f2d7dde/content.htm

It's very easy to try this out too:



create user a password blabla;
create user b password blabla;
create user c password blabla;

-> as user a:
create role rA;

create column table atab (id int);

grant select on atab to rA;

grant rA to b with admin option;

--> now user b got the role rA.
As user b:
grant rA to c;
--> now user c got the role rA

Comment: --> check:
select grantee from granted_roles where role_name ='RA'
GRANTEE 
A    
B
C

--> now revoke role rA from b and check again:
revoke rA from b;

select grantee from granted_roles where role_name ='RA';
GRANTEE 
A

--> that's it.

Comment: If you assign REPOSITORY role and have ROLE ADMIN auth. it does not apply. REPOSITORY roles are owned by _SYS_REPO and even if I delete ID who assigned role to user, user will not loose any access. I am coming from SECURITY ADMIN background you are from DB ADMIN